# toggle div on checkboxlist item

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
<div align="center">
   <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chboxlistskill" CssClass="chboxlistskill"  runat="server">
   </asp:CheckBoxList>
</div>
<div id="idotherskilldiv" class="idotherskilldiv" runat="server" style="display:none;">
   <asp:Label ID="lblskilldescription" runat="server">Description</asp:Label>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txbskilldescription" runat="server"  CssClass="txbstyle" Width="150px" Rows="3" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Suppose checkboxlist contain an item in it with value 100. How to show div on that checkbox checked and hide if that checkboxitem is unchecked using jquery..?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$('div :checkbox').change(function(){
   $('.idotherskilldiv').toggle($(':checkbox[value=100]').is(':checked'))
});
```

Comment: @kls: glad it helps :). do accept and upvote the helped answers.

Comment: I have 3 different checkboxlist on the same page when I used above code no 1 code is work, How to identify them..?

Comment: @kls: can you share the rendered html.